# Mean of all rows which meet a certain condition in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I've got the dataframe:

```
    Code  Value
1   X     135
2   D     298
3   F     301
4   G     12
5   D     203
6   X     212
7   D     401
8   D     125
```

I want to create a new column in this dataframe which calculates the mean for all the rows in the dataframe where the value in the 'Code' column is the respective value in each row.

For instance, in row 1, the 'Mean' column would find the mean of all rows where Code is 'X'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.map()` this way:

```python
df['Code_mean'] = df.Code.map(df.groupby(['Code']).Value.mean())

>>> df
Out[]:
  Code  Value  Code_mean
1    X    135     173.50
2    D    298     256.75
3    F    301     301.00
4    G     12      12.00
5    D    203     256.75
6    X    212     173.50
7    D    401     256.75
8    D    125     256.75
```

This seems to be faster than `transform` approach.

---

**EDIT: benchmark to answer comments**

```python
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_letters

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Code', 'Value'])
df.Code = [ascii_letters[26:][i] for i in np.random.randint(0, 26, 10000)]
df.Value = np.random.randint(0, 1024, 10000)

>>> %%timeit
... df['Code_mean'] = df.Code.map(df.groupby(['Code']).Value.mean())
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 ms per loop

# Reinit df before next timeit

>>> %%timeit
... df.assign(Code_mean=df.groupby('Code').transform('mean'))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.31 ms per loop
```

But after testing results does go in favour of `transform` for larger dataframes (10^6 rows)

```python
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_letters

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Code', 'Value'])
df.Code = [ascii_letters[26:][i] for i in np.random.randint(0, 26, 1000000)]
df.Value = np.random.randint(0, 1024, 1000000)

>>> %%timeit
... df['Code_mean'] = df.Code.map(df.groupby(['Code']).Value.mean())
10 loops, best of 3: 95.2 ms per loop

# Reinit df before next timeit

>>> %%timeit
... df.assign(Code_mean=df.groupby('Code').transform('mean'))
10 loops, best of 3: 68.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: What is the setting (# of rows per groups / # of rows) that you found this to be faster?

Comment: Performance here is arguably input-size dependent. Indeed this method is faster for 8 rows of data with 4 groups, but would suffer greatly with more rows of data, say 10^6. Just worth noting.

Comment: 10000 rows, 26 groups, this times around 40% faster

Comment: @FabienP Please include how you are benchmarking - I do not see similar results.

Comment: @Mitch: benchmark included, you're right there is a switch for larger dataframes. Threshold is likely around 10^5 rows

Answer (score 1):

This is a good application for the [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) method after grouping by the codes.

```
>>> df['Group_means'] = df.groupby('Code').transform('mean')
>>> df
  Code  Value  Group_means
0    X    135       173.50
1    D    298       256.75
2    F    301       301.00
3    G     12        12.00
4    D    203       256.75
5    X    212       173.50
6    D    401       256.75
7    D    125       256.75
```